# How to know if a color is in a picture

Tags: php, image

How to know if a color is in picture in PHP ?

```
function colorIsInPicture('path/to/picture.jpg', '#f55'){ }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? There is plenty of PHP functions around images: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

Comment: Brandelizer that function is to `allocate`, not `locate` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it if you have [the PHP Imagick extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) installed.

Loop over each pixel looking for your target color.

```
/**
 * Warning: Untested, but *should* work.
 * Takes a path to the image file and a color in the form 'rgb(r,g,b)'.
 * Left as exercise to reader to test and write any hex support for $sColor.
 */
function colorIsInPicture($sPath, $sColor)
{
    $im = new Imagick($sPath);
    $it = $im->getPixelIterator();

    foreach($it as $row => $pixels)
        foreach($pixels as $column => $pixel)
            if($pixel->getColorAsString() == $sColor)
                return true;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through every pixel with a function that checks what color the pixel has.

[imagecolorat()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php) (Example #2)